# PHP not capture $_POST data send by ajax jquery on same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to post data on the same page and trying to echo posted data with php with following script.

```
$('button').click(function(){

         $.ajax({               
            type: "post",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){},
            success: function(data){alert(data)},
            error: function(err) {alert(err.responseText);} 
        })

})
```

and php script is :

```
<?php echo isset($_POST['data']) ?  $_POST['data'] :''; ?>
```

my html is:

```
<form>
      <input type="hidden" name="data" value="to_success"/>
      <button type="button">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

My problem is php does not echo posted data on page, but when i post form data on another php file which is same php script; php is able to echo posted data and ajax is alert that. please help me to resolve this issue.  thanks

Comment: The `url` param should default to the current URI, but try setting it explicitly.

Comment: And of course, watch your browser's Network console to verify the request is being sent and sent to the correct path.

Comment: thanks @ Michael Berkowski. My url param is right. for same page i was not used url parameter. for another php file i was use right url

Comment: Please clarify if you are using GET or POST. Your title does not match your code,

Comment: And not know how to watch browser's network console.

Comment: Sorry @TecBrat i have edited my title as my question.

Comment: @SatendraMishra Network console: in most browsers it's F12 keyboard shortcut. Then network tab (depends on browser).

Comment: @Marek thanks for my help. I have checked and request is sent to the path witch is used.

Comment: So what error do you get in your alert box? (Or in your console).

Comment: Is this a single PHP file containing all of this code? If so, your page won't echo the POST variables as it's not being posted to when you load the page, if it works at all it will return the entire page with its HTML to the ajax success alert, which may not work if it can't interpret the return.

Comment: @putvande if i post data on same page, does not generate any error. actually after clicking the button, the data is posted so after all that php should echo the $_POST["data"] on the page but there is nothing like that

Comment: Well.. you should either get something `alert`ed or an error in your console.

Comment: @Klors you are right. this is single php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without seeing your entire PHP page as one listing, but from your description it sounds like your issue is either because of the way you are declaring your `.click()` event or the way you are posting to the page. The former is more likely.

The `$.ajax()` request will use an XMLHttpRequest object to POST to your PHP script. The PHP script should then take those values and generate the return string from the combination of the plain text in the script and the inserted echo'd values. This should then be received by the `success` method's callback function and alerted to your page as a blob of HTML text in the alert box.

Indeed, this is exactly what happens if I use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
             $.ajax({               
                type: "post",
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() {},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    alert(err.responseText);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <?php echo isset($_POST['data']) ?  $_POST['data'] :''; ?>

    <form>
       <input type="hidden" name="data" value="to_success"/>
       <button type="button">Click Me</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

However, if I comment out the lines for `$(document).ready(function(){` and its corresponding end `});`, then nothing happens when I click.

So, try wrapping your `.click()` event definition in a `$(document).ready()`.